# making program read certain parts of the file

Tags: c, file, sorting

I've a file which contains names and grades of students, and I'd like to write a program which can sort their grades (like midterm 1,midterm 2) according to user choice. I wrote as far as the choice part and opening the file, yet I don't know how to make program read only certain part of the file (like only Midterm 1 grades for example) and sort them only. Here's what I've wrote so far;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
int number;
char name[30];
char surname[30];
int midterm1,midterm2,midterm3;
} Student;

int main()
{
int choice,studentnumber,midterm1,midterm2,midterm3;
char surname;
FILE *cfPtr;

struct student *name;
name = malloc( 10 * sizeof(Student));

if ((cfPtr = fopen("grades.txt", "r")) == NULL)
printf("File cannot be opened.\n");
else {


const int STUDENTSMAX = 100;

Student students[STUDENTSMAX];
int i = 0;

while (!feof(cfPtr))

{
fscanf(cfPtr, "%d%s%s%d%d%d", &students[i].number,  &students[i].name,&students[i].surname, &students[i].midterm1, &students[i].midterm2, &students[i].midterm3);
 printf("%4d%15s%15s%10d%10d%10d\n", students[i].number, students[i].name,students[i].surname, students[i].midterm1, students[i].midterm2, students[i].midterm3);
 i++;
 }

 printf("What would you like to do? \n"
 "1- Sort according to midterm 1\n"
 "2- Sort according to midterm 2\n"
 "3- Sort according to midterm 3\n"
 "4- Exit\n");
  scanf("%d",&choice);

  while (choice != 4);{


  switch (choice) {

       case 1:
            qsort(students,10,sizeof(int),comp);
            for (i=0; i<9; i++)      
   printf("%4d%15s%15s%10d%10d%10d\n", students[i].number,  students[i].name,students[i].surname, students[i].midterm1);




    fclose(cfPtr);
   }

   system("PAUSE"); 
   return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given what might be a somewhat free form text file (based on the shown code), it probably makes sense just to read the entire file (somewhat like you are already doing) and only use the parts that you need.  If the text file has a very specific format with fixed offsets, you could seek to certain locations in the file and read a specific column value, then seek to the next offset and read the column value from the next row.  But that is probably more trouble than it is worth and would not be much more efficient (if at all).

Having said that, to sort the results, you probably need the entire file anyway.  For example, if you just read and sort the "midterm 1" value, then the result would just be sorted grades without any associated name and student number.  So without knowing more about the goal, you might consider creating a `struct` that can hold a single row (student number, name, surname, midterm1, etc.).  Then create an array of those and read each row into an element of the array.  If you know how many rows exist up front, you can allocate the array in one chunk, otherwise you might need to reallocate it as you go to grow it.

Once you have read the entire array, you could sort based on the desired value (e.g., with [`qsort`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort).

Having mentioned that, there a few problems/issues with the existing shown code:

- The second printf has fewer format specifiers (%s) than parameters.
- The third printf with the "What would you like to do" question is missing the closing paren.
- The fprintf is incorrect; it should have a file handle as the first parameter.  I suspect, though, that it was maybe meant to be `printf`?
- The final `while` loop has an extraneous semicolon (;) following its closing paren, which means that it has an empty body rather than the apparently intended `printf` and `switch` statement.
- The `switch` statement is a bit odd as written.  I assume that is the "unfinished" part.  But including the `fclose` in it seems strange.  It should probably be at the end of the main `else`.
- Using `system("PAUSE");` is maybe not the best choice.  Perhaps using `getch` would make more sense to pause for input.

**Edit**  Here is some additional information in response to your comment asking for more details.  This sounds like homework to me, so it doesn't seem right just to give the answer.  But here is one way to do it:

- Define a `struct` with the 6 items that are in the file (basically put in the 6 variables that you currently have defined as local variables).
- Declare a local variable (e.g., `grades`) as a `pointer` to struct that you defined.
- Use `malloc` to allocate memory and assign it to the pointer just mentioned.  The amount of memory is perhaps the trickiest part of this whole thing.  The size parameter to `malloc` will be something like `numRecs * sizeof( yourstruct )`.  The question is what `numRecs` should be.  If this is an assignment and you were told how many records there would be (a maximum), then just use that. If, though, it is "unknown", then there are a couple of ways of dealing with that.  One is to just guess at a number (e.g., 100) and then while reading them in a loop use `realloc` if you exceed 100.  The other alternative (probably less efficient) would be to use two loops - read through them once without storing them but just count them and then allocate the known size and read them again.  I would use the realloc version.
- Replace the use of the local variables with the array (that was `malloc`ed).  For example, instead of `studentnumber` you would use `grades[arraypos].studentnumber`.  While you read them in, keep a counter of how many there are.  You can then use `qsort` to sort the array.

**Edit 2**

- Your struct definition looks correct except that the `FILE *cfPtr;` member should not be in it. It should still be a local variable.
- For ease of use, you can define the struct as `typedef struct { ... } Student;`.  That way you can just use `Student` instead of `struct Student` in the code.  Note that I capitalized the name (personal preference in naming to make it not look like a variable name).
- For the malloc, you are close.  But as written, it is allocating space for a single record.  You would need something like this:  `name = malloc( 50 * sizeof( struct student ));`  (or `malloc( 50 * sizeof( Student ));` if you change it to use the typedef.  That assumes there would not be 50 or fewer records to read from the file.

Comment: My problem is, I really don't know how to read the records into an array. I started with the first part;

int choice,studentnumber,midterm1,midterm2,midterm3;
   char name[30];
   char surname[30];
   FILE *cfPtr;
which was actually meant to be struct going into array part, yet failed. Any guidence with that? Sorry I'm a starter, and a really bad one :D. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited the original post thanks to your suggestions. I defined the struct part, think I've got the declaring local variable as a pointer part too(probably not :D) but I'm really not familliar with the "malloc" function. I've searched around, is the part I wrote right?

Comment: My text file looks like "100201 name surname 10 20 30" and there are 10 of those. As records, should I count them as word count (like 6 * 10) or as 10 lines?

Comment: @dawsonrose:  1 line in this case is one record.  A single line in the file equates to one of the structures you defined.  So the multiplier should be 10.

Comment: Alright, fixed the original post again. But I don't have an idea on how to replace them and write the array part, and none of my searches are returning me with any actual useful info :/ Arrays are my problem :D

Comment: @dawsonrose:  You are probably going to have to start learning to use google now :)  The first hit on my search of "using arrays in C" [produced this info on arrays](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-arrays/).  I only looked at it for 5 seconds, but it might be a good starting point.

Comment: Oh wow that is actually humiliating :D Guess I really don't know how to search "properly", but believe me I've been looking for a long time. So according to this, I've to define every structure object and write what they include, aka every line one by one? And then define them into arrays. Is there a way to do that without writing what's in the file into the code, like make it read them by itself?

Comment: You don't have to hard code it into the program.  Just use the existing loop that you have already written and read the values into the array that you malloc'd.  For example, instead of `studentname` you use `name[i].studentname`.

Comment: Alright I edited the original post again, now trying to write qsort function, yet how do I write the "compare" function? Does the code make any sensE?